# filter an arraylist dynamically based on a string value- kotlin

Tags: kotlin, arraylist, filter

I want to filter an arraylist indexes and filter a doc based on the docid I provide.

The below code works for 0th index but cant search the whole list and findout the docid

```
  var results =
this._items?.userItems?.filter { it -> it.requests.get(0).doc == docid }
```

Kindly suggest the better way of doing It.

Any help is highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want to keep only the `userItems` that have any `request` with the given `docid`, you can use `it.requests.any { request -> request.doc == docid }`.

From the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/any.html) (see the overload that takes in a predicate):

> Returns true if at least one entry matches the given predicate.

If you want to get all the `requests` with the given `docid` instead, you can use: `userItems.flatMap { it.requests }.filter { it.doc == docid }`